# particle emit collision

Tags: particles, collision

im trying to tip out a bin via particle emission. the barrels bottom is doubled as a emitter. the bin itself is a collision object. i have the problem that the particles are intersecting and sometimes even passing through. is there a simple way to increase the collision margin, like in rigid body systems? or is there a better way to do this effect?

Edit: Or is there a way to boolean away particles aorund the barrel?

[image: particle system tip out]

Comment: What type of collision are you using for the bucket? (Convex Hull/bounding box etc.)? Could you share your file so that we can take a look?

Comment: maybe you should use rigid body rather than particles?

Comment: as I know  the collision type is a setting of the rigid body world, not of the particle collision settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/8usFA.png

Comment: @moonboots, yeah maybe thats the only workaround, but i wanted to have a kind of unlimited emission (and faster viewport display)..

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: i did it with rigid body now, thanks though